# visualization_msgs: how to draw a circumference

Tags: ros, visualization-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to draw a circunference on RVIZ using for that the visualization_msgs/marker...
I am using the cylinder shape, but I actually want to draw a
circumference.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64801/visualization_msgs:-how-to-draw-a-circumference/) by [MiguelRobPinto](https://answers.ros.org/users/2036/miguelrobpinto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can define a [line strip](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker#Line_Strip_.28LINE_STRIP.3D4.29) that approximates the circle as a regular polygon with however many sides you want.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0